# Lightbox overlay not displaying on Chrome but works well on Chrome Canary

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, lightbox2

I've got some issues on Lightbox Overlay which it displays perfectly on Chrome Canary, Safari, Firefox and IE. Except for Chrome (version 33).

Screenshots:
** Lightbox on any browser except Chrome : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0952i236a2
** Lightbox on Chrome : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0522i2378a

Another weird thing is, the Gray black overlay will popup IF

1. I resized my browser
2. Hovered and inspected an HTML element on the page

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!.

Comment: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/187

Comment: yep, same here. Also thanks a lot @MatTheCat for github link, that's help.

Comment: I've got a lightbox JS plugin you can use if you just want a solution

Answer (score 0):

can you make the overlay styles set to

```
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
```

worth a shot overwriting the default styles if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS rule fixed the problem w/o sacrificing the fade:

```
.lightboxOverlay { 
   overflow: scroll; 
}
```

This worked for me and was found [here](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/187).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [bug in Chrome 33 & 34](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345894) (I've got 34 and can confirm that it is still happening). According to the bug report, this should be fixed in Chrome 35 (it was released to beta April 10th).

Until that is released, it seems the best fix is to disable fading. Adding scrollbars (overflow: scroll;) seems to work as well, but then you have an extra set of scrollbars.

I'm having this problem in jquery.blockUI.js. For others out there, you can update this line...

For **Lightbox** users, try adding this CSS...

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ 
    .lightboxOverlay { overflow: scroll; }
    .lightboxOverlay::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; }
}
```

For **jquery.blockUI.js** users, search for...

```
lyr2._fadeIn(opts.fadeIn, cb1);
```

Replace with...

```
lyr2.show();
```