# jQuery version conflict between lightbox and google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, lightbox, conflict

My lightbox works with this code included. But Google map API fails to load.

```
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
.
.
.
.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

But if i exclude the bottom jQuery include as shown below, map works but Lightbox doesnt:

```
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
.
.
.
.
<!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> -->
```

I also tried

```
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<!--<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> -->
<!--<script src="<?php echo HTTP_JS; ?>/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  -->
.
.
.
.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here, both Maps and Lightbox work but the semi opaque overlay doesnt show up.

Too many ppl have worked on this code, so i don't know why son many versions have been included together. Also I am a fresher. So please need some help here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should try the last one again, but then load jQuery first and jQuery migrate after.

Comment: i just found out that the last option is working on other browsers but chrome. And it works on chrome on resizing the window.

Its a whole other issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448086/lightbox-overlay-not-displaying-on-chrome-but-works-well-on-chrome-canary